# integrating email with Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, email

I'm trying to integrate Oracle XE (11g) with email (on Linux). This includes sending and receiving the complete email, as well as receiving attachments and loading them into Oracle.

Specifically, I'm looking for a linux command line email client that will read emails regularly from a pop3 or imap mailbox, then load the email and attachment into a table tables in an Oracle XE database.

I've seen a solution using the Database Java, but Oracle XE does not have the Java subsystem enabled (and it doesn't handle attachments).

The alternative could be using Fetchmail, and Procmail along then SQL*Loader to load emails into the Database, I have worked out how to monitor an email address and extract individual attachments from a received email, but can't work out how to extract the email body into a single file, if anyone can help with the correct .procmailrc configuration.

Thanks